# How can I determine if a Jinja2 template block is empty?

Tags: templates, flask, block, jinja2

I'd like to detect if a Jinja2 template block content is empty or not.  Something like this:

```
{% block foo %}{% endblock foo %}{% if foo %} - {% endif %}Blah Blah Blah
```

What I want is conditional text *outside* the block definition itself.  In the contrived example, I want to be able to insert a conditional string `-` *after* the block if and *only* if the block has been overridden and is not empty.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Simply call the block:

```
{% if self.foo() %} - {% endif %}
```

Comment: I am not worthy!  Thanks, that works great.  Did I miss that in the docs, or is it one of those 'pro tips' items...?

Comment: @Inactivist - it is buried in the [template designer docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#child-template) "If you want to print a block multiple times you can however use the special self variable and call the block with that name".

Comment: Note that it's important for the block in question to be completely empty. I had a newline in mine that was evaluating to the empty string but still counted as truthy.

Comment: @BrianPeterson: Use the [`trim`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#trim) filter to ignore leading and trailing whitespace: `{% if self.foo() | trim %} - {% endif %}`.